# How to "seq" plugin settings in a multi-project sbt build

Tags: scala, sbt, subproject

I am converting a single-project `build.sbt` to a multi-project `build.sbt`, which is always a PITA. There is this obscure syntax to make plugin settings available. E.g. before

```
seq(appbundle.settings: _*)
```

How do I do this with sub-projects. E.g.

```
lazy val views = Project(
  id        = "views",
  base      = file("views"),
  dependencies = Seq(core),
  settings  = commonSettings ++ Seq(
    seq(appbundle.settings: _*),    // ???
    name        := "views",
    description := ...
  )
)
```

This just gives me an error

```
 found   : Seq[sbt.Def.SettingsDefinition]
 required: Seq[sbt.Def.Setting[_]]
  settings  = commonSettings ++ Seq(
                             ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add them using `++` to the overall settings

```
lazy val views = Project(
  id        = "views",
  base      = file("views"),
  dependencies = Seq(core),
  settings  = commonSettings ++ appbundle.settings ++ Seq(
    name        := "views",
    description := ...
  )
)
```